# JavaScript string normalize() does not work in some cases - why?

Tags: javascript, unicode, normalize

In my debugger I can see an object is retrieved with a unicode character. e.g.

```
{
    name: "(Other\uff09"
}
```

If this object is referenced using the var `myObj` in the debugger I see that

```
myObj.name.normalize()
```

returns

```
"(Other\uff09"
```

If instead I use

```
"(Other\uff09".normalize()
```

it returns

```
"(Other)"
```

Why?

Comment: Your `name` property contains a literal backslash, not a Unicode escape sequence.

Comment: Ah, the devtools / browser displays them the same but they are different characters under the covers. That makes sense. Any thoughts on how I can escape them? This value is used in an email address. But the module treats the characters as invalid and strips this particular address. I want to stop that behaviour as we need the address to be present.

Answer (score 0):

I've learnt a little since posting this question. Initially I thought that `\uff09` was equivalent to `)`. It's not, instead it's `）`, aka [Full Width Right Parenthesis](https://codepoints.net/U+FF09?lang=en).

This essentially means that the opening and closing brackets do not match. e.g. `(` is not *closed* by `）`. This is causing parsing issues for the [NodeMailer AddressParser](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/lib/addressparser/index.js#L266) module I'm using.

To normalize it I'm using

```
JSON.parse(`"(Other\uff09"`).normalize("NFKC")
```

which translates the string to `(Other)` rather than `(Other）`.

Breaking this down

```
JSON.parse(`"(Other\uff09"`)
```

where the double quotes is required, produces `(Other）`. i.e. It converts the unicode escape characters into the character they represent.

Then

```
.normalize("NFKC")
```

converts that into `(Other)`.

This worked for me in this sample. I still need to see if it scales up.